# Como definir ou retornar o DateTimerPicker em branco

Tags: c#, webforms

Como faço para definir ou trazer o `datetimerpicker` em branco ao iniciar o form e adicionar a data só quando for selecionado? Preciso trazer esse componente em branco para adiciona-lo à data de admissão de um funcionário.

Comment: Estamos falando de um sistema WebForms?

Comment: Não, estou criando em Windows Form.